# Use multiple targets for same project to load different resource images

Tags: xcode, target

I have a project with a storyboard and some resource images.

I want to create another app which will have all the same interactions etc except for a different set of resource images which is also added to the project in a different folder. I tried adding a new target but when I try to debug it, I cannot get it to run the original storyboard.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Right click on a target and choose to duplicate
2. Change the name of the target to your choice
3. Rename the duplicated .plist file name to the name you chose in step 2
4. Click on the control where you chose where to start the application for debug and select Manage schemes
5. Delete the duplicated scheme (it would have "copy" in its name most likely)
6. Click on "Auto create schemes now" to get the updated name

Select the scheme you want to debug in the control mentioned in step 4.